# Is it possible to launch Chrome which is already installed on the Android Emulator via Appium?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write some test scripts using Appium and ChromeDriver for a website visited from an Android tablet. To do so I've been trying to find a way to launch Chrome (which is already installed) instead of passing the APK and installing it when the test runs but I have not been successful.

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me if this is even possible in the first place and if it is I'd be even more grateful if you could tell me how it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the [solution here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/u1z3hMJusWk). Instead of setting the *app* capability I had to set the *browserName* capability as *Chrome* (Chrome has to be already installed on the emulator of course)

Answer (score 2):

Use this piece of code

```
    new DesiredCapabilities();
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");

    try 
    {
        url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver(url, capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("URL init error");
    }
```

Cheers